# Getting an error while adding a role in Magento

Tags: magento

I am setting up a Magento(v. 1.6.1.0) site.
To access the API, I needed to create a rule (Admin > System > Web Services > Rules > Add new rule).
When I click the button, I got the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /home/dinamal7/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Api/Editroles.php on line 52
```

I ran some research about the issue but couldn't find any solution. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sam, looks like there is some problem with the object calling that particular function.  As you can see, it is indicating the core file, which is not supposed to have any errors.  You can try and replace the "core" folder of your current installation with the one extracted fresh.  This should do the trick.

Comment: Then, probably the extension that we purchased caused the problem. I'll check that out. Thanks.